# Can I work in USA aviation maintenance without U.S. citizenship?

Tags: aircraft-maintenance

I am currently working outside of the US but have all the aviation maintenance degrees, and I am moving to the US.

Can I work in the USA if I don’t have citizenship?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I be US aircraft maintenance technician?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/87346/how-can-i-be-us-aircraft-maintenance-technician)

Comment: This question is about immigration & employment law, not aviation.

Comment: Suggest migrating to Expatriates.stackexchange

Comment: I’m not sure if there is an SE group for immigration and naturalization questions, but that would seem to be more related to that than aviation.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is more likely to be answerable in [expatriates.se]